# Ruby encoding issue with nested key

Tags: ruby

In order to solve the [problem with YAML incompatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199392/how-to-parse-rubys-yaml-in-php-sfyaml-and-spyc-wont-do-it-right) I'm trying to write a command-line script in Ruby. The problem it that I'm totally unfamiliar with Ruby.

So I've made the following script:

```
require 'json'
require 'yaml'

thing = YAML.load('--- 
author_id: 
- 0
- 1
subject: 
- ""
- !binary |
  0KHQtNC10LvQsNGC0Ywg0LPRgNCw0LzQvtGC0L3Ri9C5INCy0L3QtdGI0L3Q
  uNC5INCy0LjQtCDQtNC70Y8g0LjQvNC10Y7RidC10LPQvtGB0Y8=
')

puts thing.to_json
# puts thing['subject'][1].to_json # Issues the same error
```

And now I'm getting `yaml2json.rb:15:in`encode': "\xD0" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)`

How to make it think that the decoded base64 is in UTF-8? Generally I don't know the exact name of a key, `subject` is only an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
thing['subject'][1].force_encoding('utf-8')
puts thing.to_json
```

Produces:

```
{"author_id":[0,1],"subject":["","Сделать грамотный внешний вид для имеющегося"]}
```

Since you don't know where the strings will be, the best option that comes to mind at the moment is to recursively traverse the Hash, force_encoding all strings.  There may be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Could you suggest the snapshot for recursive traverse? I know, stupid question, but I'm too weak in Ruby.

Comment: I did it eventually. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I was catching a few hours of sleep.  It looks like you came up with a good solution posted as an answer to your other question.